# Prevent textarea from clearing out when a new text is typed in

Tags: javascript, onclick, textarea, onblur

Here's my code for the text area.

```
<textarea style="width: 95%;" rows="6" name="feedback[<?=$r_uid;?>]" disabled="disabled" onclick="this.value='';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'No feedback provided':this.value;" maxlength="800"></textarea>
```

When a user clicks it, it clears out. And if they leave it blank, the text "No feedback provided" appears. However, if they type something else and click outside the box, the text area retains it.

The problem, however, is if they click inside the box. The new text typed in is cleared out. Is there a way to prevent it from clearing out if a new text is typed in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your onClick event:

```
if (this.value == 'No feedback provided') this.value = '';
```

...
Note that you only targeting `click`! what about **keyboard navigation**? use `onfocus` instead of `onclick`:

```
<textarea style="width: 95%;" rows="6" name="feedback[<?=$r_uid;?>]" disabled="disabled" 
onfocus="if (this.value == 'No feedback provided') this.value = '';" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'No feedback provided':this.value;" maxlength="800"></textarea>
```

Note that inline scripts are deprecated and hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. +1 for inline scripts advise. I'm still trying to learn the ropes. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This part in your code clears it. Remove it ;)

```
onclick="this.value='';"
```

Basically, when clicked on the element, the value of the clicked element = ''. So empty.